# How to write a monad instance for a pair where both arguments have the same type?

Tags: haskell, monads

Suppose I have a type `Pair`:

```
data Pair a = Pair a a
```

What is the right way to write a monad instance for it? My idea is roughly this:

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Pair a) where
  Pair a1 a2 <> Pair b1 b2 = Pair (a1 <> b1)(a2 <> b2)

instance Monad Pair where
  return = pure
  (Pair a b) >>= f = f a <> f b
```

Is it correct? If so then where to specify that `b`-type in the `Pair b` is a semigroup?

Comment: What do you want to do with the monad?

Comment: Nothing, just reading a chapter about monads in a book and trying to understand how they work. Pure learning exercise.

Comment: Hint: `Pair a` is isomorphic to `Bool -> a`, and the latter has a very well-known `Monad` instance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, the only correct monad instance of `Pair` is as follows.

```hs
instance Monad Pair where
    m >>= f = joinPair (f <$> m)

joinPair :: Pair (Pair a) -> Pair a
joinPair (Pair (Pair x _) (Pair _ y)) = Pair x y
```

The reason this is the correct monad instance is because `Pair` is a [representable functor](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/07/29/representable-functors/).

```hs
instance Representable Pair where
    type Rep Pair = Bool

    index (Pair x _) False = x
    index (Pair _ y) True  = y

    tabulate f = Pair (f False) (f True)
```

Turns out, for every representable functor `(>>=)` is equivalent to the following [`bindRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/representable-functors-3.2.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Representable.html#g:8) function.

```hs
bindRep :: Representable f => f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b
bindRep m f = tabulate (\a -> index (f (index m a)) a)
```

If we specialize the `bindRep` function to `Pair` we get the following.

```hs
bindRep :: Pair a -> (a -> Pair b) -> Pair b
bindRep (Pair x y) f = tabulate (\a -> index (f (index (Pair x y) a)) a)
                     = Pair (index (f x) False) (index (f y) True)
--                          |_________________| |________________|
--                                   |                   |
--                           (1st elem of f x)   (2nd elem of f y)
```

The following blog post by Adelbert Chang explains it better. [Reasoning with representable functors](https://www.adelbertc.com/representable-functors/).

---

Here's another way to prove uniqueness. Consider the left and right identity monad instance laws.

```hs
return a >>= k = k a -- left identity law

m >>= return = m     -- right identity law
```

Now, for the `Pair` data type `return x = Pair x x`. Hence, we can specialize these laws.

```hs
Pair a a >>= k = k a     -- left identity law

m >>= \x -> Pair x x = m -- right identity law
```

So, what should the definition of `>>=` be in order to satisfy these two laws?

```hs
Pair x y >>= f = Pair (oneOf [x1, x2, y1, y2]) (oneOf [x1, x2, y1, y2])
    where Pair x1 y1 = f x
          Pair x2 y2 = f y
```

The `oneOf` function returns one of the elements of the list non-deterministically.

Now, if our `>>=` function is to satisfy the left identity law then when `x = y` then `x1 = x2` and `y1 = y2` and the result must be `Pair (oneOf [x1, x2]) (oneOf [y1, y2])`.

Similarly, if our `>>=` function is to satisfy the right identity law then `x1 = y1 = x` and `x2 = y2 = y` and the result must be `Pair (oneOf [x1, y1]) (oneOf [x2, y2])`.

Hence, if you want to satisfy both laws then the only valid result is `Pair x1 y2`.

Comment: @dfeuer Updated my answer to prove uniqueness using the monad instance laws.

Comment: You seem to appeal implicitly to parametricity. I imagine this is unavoidable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your proof begins with (and hinges critically on) the definition `return x = Pair x x`. This is the only sensible definition in Haskell -- but only because of parametricity. In a non-parametric context, one might wonder whether `return 0 = Pair 1 2; return x = Pair x x` might be a possible choice, say.

Comment: @DanielWagner I can't prove my intuition but I believe that a non-parametric monad instance of `Pair` would not be able to satisfy all the monad laws. Consider the expression `(m >>= k) >>= h`. If `m >>= k` evaluates to `return x` for some `x` then the entire expression should evaluate to `k x` because of the left identity law. However, if `return x` is not `Pair x x` then `m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)` could evaluate to something other than `k x`. Hence, it would violate the associativity law. However, I don't know how to prove this hypothesis. Here's a code example. https://jsfiddle.net/zf0eL9jk/

Comment: @AaditMShah I suspect both standalone instances of `k x` in your text were intended to be `h x`, right? If so, then I think there's still quite a lot of holes in your argument, it seems to me -- we are asking if a lawful non-parametric definition exists, but all you appear to have argued is that an unlawful non-parametric definition exists.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, good catch. It was supposed to be `h x`.

Comment: For any two monads M, N, the product (M a, N a) is also a monad. The pair (a, a) is a special case where both M and N are identity functors.

Comment: @winitzki Whoa, that actually makes the derivation of `>>=` much simpler. Just follow the types.

Answer (score 4):

Functor and applicative instances are easy. The monad instance has taken a while to me.

```
data Pair a = Pair a a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Pair where 
  fmap f (Pair a b) = Pair (f a) (f b)

instance Applicative Pair where 
  pure a = Pair a a
  (Pair f g) <*> (Pair a b) = Pair (f a) (g b)

instance Monad Pair where 
  return = pure
  (Pair a b) >>= f = let Pair a' _ = f a 
                         Pair _ b' = f b
                     in  Pair a' b'
```

The way I've come to this solution is by applying the monad laws. Easily you can check with an example that identity law doesn't hold if you take `Pair a' a''` or `Pair b' b''` or `Pair a' b'` nor `Pair a'' b''`. So the only solutions must be in the diagonals. Defining

```
(m >>= f) = Pair (first . f . first $ m) (second . f . second $ m)
```

where `first` and `second` are the obvious ones, you can proof all of the laws.

Comment: Check the laws!

Comment: Yes, `Pair a' b''` is the correct one. See my answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754645/783743

Comment: @AaditMShah why you have to spoil the ending like that

Comment: So bad... you have to let people think

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to make `Pair` into `Monad` by having `join` that takes the diagonal.of the 2×2 square. `return` has no other choice but replicate its argument. This turns `Pair` into essentially a fixed length `ZipList`.

Of course this definition of `join` discards some data. This may or may not be important.

Comment: could you write some sketch here?

Answer (score 0):

A Monad instance may not place any constraints on the type of data it contains (the `a` here). It must treat that data as fully opaque. I don't think your `Pair` type admits a Monad instance (or Applicative), because there is no way to turn a pair of pairs into a single pair without either losing some of the data, or using it in some way not permitted by the typeclass definition.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with losing some of the data as far as monad laws go.

Answer (score 0):

### Why I am answering

I was curious to know what the practical usages of the `Pair a` monad are, especially considering that the only valid implementation of `(>>=)` actually throws away half of the data, so I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587591/known-estabilished-usecases-for-the-monad-instance-of-an-homogeneous-pair).

It turns out that the [answer I accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66588610/5825294) is a very interesting answer to this question too (and was contained in Daniel Wagner's comment under the present question, but I hadn't noticed it), so I will elaborate it a bit here, because I've learned a lot from it.

### The short answer: `(a,a)` and `Bool -> a` are the same thing

So the short answer is that the types `Pair a`, or more simply `(a,a)`, and `Bool -> a` are isomorphic: feeding a `(a,a)` to `fst`/`snd` is equivalent to feeding a `Bool -> a` function with `True`/`False` (or `False`/`True`, it's just a choice). The two isomorphisms are actually shown in the (deleted) answer from [Zhiltsoff Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11143763/zhiltsoff-igor):

> ```hs
> funToPair :: (Bool -> a) -> (a, a)
> funToPair f = (f True, f False)
>
> pairToFun :: (a, a) -> Bool -> a
> pairToFun (x, y) True = x
> pairToFun (x, y) False = y
> ```

As a consquence, whichever way `Bool -> a` is a monad, `(a,a)`/`Pair a` is a monad in the same way.

### But `(a,a)`'s `Monad` throws information away... so does `Bool -> a`!

What bugged me at this point was that it's so apparent that the `Monad` instance for `(a,a)`/`Pair a`, thoroughly explained in [Aadit M Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754645/5825294), throws away data, whereas the `Monad` instance for `Bool -> a`... doesn't...?

Fatally wrong! The `Monad` instance for `r -> a` (with generic `r`, not just `Bool`) throws away information all the time! How? Let's look at the well known implementation of `>>=`:

```hs
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

Now remember that a function of type `x -> y` is equivalent to a tuple of type `(y,y,...,y)` with as many entries as the number of possible values of type `x` (***not*** `y`).

What about `k`? `k` is a binary function, let's say of type `x -> y -> z`, so it can be fed with the cartesian product of the values that inhabit the type `x` and those that inhabit the type of `y`. If `x` and `y` are inhabited by `m` and `n` values respectively, then `k` is equivalent to a tuple of type `(z,z,...,z)` with as many entries as `m*n`, and that is the information that comes with `k`.

Now the question is whether `(>>=)` makes use of all that information. No, it doesn't! `(>>=)` is feeding `k` with only `n` possible inputs: the second argument `r` is any value of type `x`, whereas the first argument is **the single value corresponding to `r` via `f`**.

If we think of mathematical functions, we are saying that, for fixed unary function *f: A → B* and binary function *k: B×A → C*, `f >>= k` is the unary function that does *t ∈ A → k(f(t),t) ∈ C*, i.e. it's a restriction of *k* to the curve parametrized by the equations *x = f(t)* and *y = t*.

Going back to `Bool -> a`, the signature of `(>>=)` specilizes to

```hs
(>>=) :: (Bool -> a) -> (a -> Bool -> b) -> Bool -> b
f >>= k = \r -> k (f r) r
```

which we can rewrite as follows, just to make the obvious more apparent:

```hs
(>>=) f k r
  | r == True  = k (f True)  True
  | r == False = k (f False) False
-- remember this
```

What's obvious in the above? If we feed `f >>= k` with `True`, we'll only use `f True`, thus throwing away the other half of the data, `f False`. Similarly, if we call `(f >>= k) False`, we throw away whatever `f True` is. This way of throwing away half of the information contained in `k` mirrors exactly what is throw away via the `_` placeholders for `(a,a)` aka `Pair a` (adaptation from [Ismor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753984/5825294)):

```hs
instance Monad Pair where 
  return = pure
  (Pair a b) >>= k = let Pair a' _  = k a
                         Pair _  b' = k b
                     in  Pair a' b'
```

Indeed, if we define `fst' (Pair a _) = a` and `snd' (Pair _ b) = b` (these are mirroring `fst` and `snd` for `(,)`), then `(>>=)` can be written simply as follows

```hs
(>>=) :: Pair a -> (a -> Pair b) -> Pair b
p >>= k = (fst' (k (fst' p)),
           snd' (k (snd' p)))
```

Which is in my opinion strikingly similar to the code I marked with `-- remember this`, with `fst'` mirrors `True` and `snd'` mirrors `False`.

By the way, for the following, let's take note of the type of `(>>=)` in the case we were allowed to write it for `(a,a)`:

```hs
(>>=) :: (a,a) -> (a -> (b,b)) -> (b,b)
```

### What about `(a,b)` when `a` and `b` are the same type?

This was the last doubt I had: *since [`(a,b)` is a `Monad` in `b` provided `a` is a `Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-452), in the special case that the type `b` is equal to the type `a` (and `b` has to be a `Monoid`), do we get the same instance as above?*

No, the question above is ill-posed, the flaw being in the part *"in the special case that the type `b` is equal to the type `a`"*. This hypothesis is simply not possible because for a type constructor to be a `Monad`, it has to have one and only one free type parameter:

- `(a,b)` is made a `Monad` in the free parameter `b`, meaning that `b` will be allowed to vary according to the second argument to `(>>=)`, whereas the type `a` will stay the same through the `(>>=)` operator;
- `(a,a)` is made a `Monad` in the free parameter `a`, meaning that `a` will be allowed to vary according to the second argument to `(>>=)`, whereas... nothing, that's it, all explained in the previous part of the answer.