# Is a pair of homogeneous types inherently not a monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, functor, applicative

This is a wrapper to a couple of two objects of the same type

```hs
data Pair a = Pair a a deriving (Show)
--newtype Pair a = Pair (a,a) deriving (Show) -- not this
```

It seems to be easily made a [functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor), by having the mapping function act on both values,

```hs
instance Functor Pair where
  fmap f (Pair a b) = Pair (f a) (f b)
```

and the functor laws seem to hold too, am I wrong? Ok, this instance seems pretty useless, but at least it looks intuitive to me: what else would I want to do, given a function and a wrapper to two values, instead of doing this?

We can also make it an [applicative functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html)

```hs
instance Applicative Pair where
  pure a = Pair a a
  Pair f g <*> Pair x y =  Pair (f x) (g y)
```

even though I've not checked if composition and interchange laws are verified (identity and homomorphism are). Like before, I see this instance a bit trivial but easy to look at: what else would I do, instead of this?

However, I don't see how it can be made a `Monad`. `(>>=)`'s second arument should be a function which acts on **one** entity of the type given to the `Monad` type constructor, right? In this case, however, `Pair` contains **two**, possibly different, values. So there's a problem of choosing how a function, say, of type `Int -> Pair Int` should act on the inside of, say, `Pair 3 4`. I guess I could invented it, but having it adhere to the monad laws does not seem obvious to me. Plus it should be consistent with the above `Functor` and `Applicative` instances.

Is there an obvious reason why `Pair` cannot be made a monad? Or maybe it can, and I'm just confused?

Comment: I can't answer your question firmly either way, but note this is essentially a `ZipList` limited to 2 elements, and `ZipList` is well known for being an `Applicative` but not a `Monad`. (Although I've never seen a proof that it can't be a Monad.)

Comment: The key is to recognize that `>>=` has to do some additional work before returning a new `Pair`. `(Pair x y) >>= f`, as intermediate values, produces *two* pairs, one (`f x == Pair x' y'`) based on `x` and one (`f y == Pair x'' y''`) on `y`. `>>=` then has to merge them, and the only law-abiding way to do that is to produce `Pair x'' y''`, rather than one of the other three options.

Comment: Your homogeneous `Pair` is isomoprhic to `(->) Bool`, which is a monad. This generalizes to tuples.

Comment: @chepner, I think you mean `Pair x' y''`.

Comment: @chepner, why is that? It seems that what you say underlies an asymmetry between `Pair`'s arguments.

Comment: @dfeuer, then why not `Pair x'' y'`?

Comment: @chi, are you then saying that `Pair` can be a monad? If so, how? Maybe someone could vote to reopen the question?

Comment: This question as posed is really a duplicate of the other one. You should ask a new question about why the instance Aadit M. Shah gives is unique. I would be very interested in whether the answer relies essentially on parametricity.

Comment: @Enrico See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58753984/1126841. You need `Pair x' y''` (as dfeuer corrected my typo) to ensure that your definition of `>>=` obeys the monad laws.

Comment: @Enrico Convert a `Pair a` to a `Bool -> a` in the obvious way. Use the standard `(->) Bool` monad definition. Convert any resulting `(->) Bool t` back to `Pair t`. I mean, once you understand it's isomorphic to something (`Bool -> a`) which we already know it's a monad, it's just a matter of copying the same instance and apply the isomorphism so to adapt the instance to the new type (`Pair a`). You can try doing this as a nice exercise.

Comment: @chi, ok, I'll try to "parse" your comment in the weekend. I'm still quite _ignorant_ about morphisms and category theory in general.

Comment: Any homogeneous pair `p` can be converted to a function from bool i.e. `\b -> if b then fst p else snd p`. Vice versa, any such function `f` can be concerted to an homogeneous pair `(f True, f False)`. Further, these conversions simplify (they are inverses). So, once you know how to handle `Bool -> ...` as a monad, just apply the conversions as needed (possibly in both directions) to the same instance. It's not obvious at first, but it can be a great learning exercise.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see. In other words `Bool -> a` and `(a,a)` are isomorphic because they are both ways of representing only two results/values. As regards _how_ `(a,a)` can be a `Monad`, I'll refer to the linked answer to understand why `>>=` has to be like that, and, if something is not clear to me, I'll ask a separate question to address it and link it off a comment here (or I'll simply modify this to get it reopened).