# Why Monad instance of pair on Hackage has no implementation for return?

Tags: haskell, monads

While writing down [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753545/how-to-write-a-monad-instance-for-a-pair-where-both-arguments-have-the-same-type/66721243#66721243), mostly to get a better understanding of pairs as monads, I stumbed into [this source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-452) on Hackage where I read, in reference to the `Monad` instance of `(,) a` only this

```hs
instance Monoid a => Monad ((,) a) where
    (u, a) >>= k = case k a of (v, b) -> (u <> v, b)
```

where's `return`??? I expected to find something like this

```hs
    return a = (mempty, a)
```

in addition to the two lines above. Is this definition of `return` somehow implied by something else? Or maybe it's defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In modern versions of Haskell (specifically, `base` version 4.8.0.0 and newer, corresponding to GHC version 7.10.1 and newer), [the `Monad` class has the default implementation `return = pure`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#return), so instances of it only need to define `>>=`. This was a result of the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal).

Comment: (... and so we find `instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a) where pure x = (mempty, x)` [just above the same source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-446) linked in the question )